# Rails checking for style in a helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails, and trying to figure this out: I have a list of goods, which needs to appear in different forms on different pages. There's a helper method that seems to allow this to happen - essentially, the view says render _goods.html.haml , and it renders the appropriate template. Here's an abbreviated version of goods.html.haml :

```
    - style ||= :full
      - cache [ 'v4', good, style ] do
      - if style == :full
         .listed_item.group(id="good_#{ good.id }")
         %h4= link_to good.name 
      - elsif style == :search_result
       = render 'goods/search_result', good: good 
      - elsif style == :lightbox
       = render 'goods/lightbox', good: good 
      - elsif style == :card
     %li
    = link_to photo_for(good.user, :thumb), good.user
    - else
     %li
      %span.name= link_to good.name
```

I checked the views for each, and found that each of the looked like it was embedded in a class of that name, i.e. search_result was in a search_result class. So I tried nesting the goods I wanted to appear in the lightbox class under a

```
<div class="lightbox">
```

, but no luck. It keeps defaulting to full no matter what I do. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where / how is the style variable set?  Can you show the controller#action code?

Comment: Hmmm, unless I'm missing something, the style's not set in the controller. Here's the controller: https://github.com/ourgoods/ourgoods/blob/master/app/controllers/goods_controller.rb

Comment: Getting a 404 on that URL.  Can you search your app for it; maybe it's in the base controller or in the parent view and then passed to the partial as a local var.

Comment: Good call! It apparently an argument I'm supposed to call when I render the view - render goods, :style => :card for example. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be rendering `_goods` without passing style, try:

```
render partial: 'whatever_is_your_path/goods', locals: { style: :lightbox }
```

I am not sure why this way sometimes does not work for me, but try it anyway:

```
render 'whatever_is_your_path/goods', style: :lightbox
```

By the way, if none of these work, you should put in your question how you are calling render to draw your partial.